# How to access arrayList values through getter in another class by using Bloc - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist, getter-setter, bloc

I'm trying to get arrayList data into another class through getter with the help of `blocProvider` but here in another class it gives following error:

```
The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'
```

**Here is Bloc class where I defied `getter` to get arrayList values**

```
class GlobalBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>> _medicineList$;
  BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>> get medicineList$ => _medicineList$; //getter  <--


  GlobalBloc() {
    _medicineList$ = BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>>.seeded([]);
    makeMedicineList();
  }


  Future makeMedicineList() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedUser = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> jsonList = sharedUser.getStringList('medicines');
    List<Medicine> prefList = [];
    if (jsonList == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      for (String jsonMedicine in jsonList) {
        Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonMedicine);
        Medicine tempMedicine = Medicine.fromJson(userMap);
        prefList.add(tempMedicine);
      }
      _medicineList$.add(prefList);
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _medicineList$.close();
  }
}
```

**Here is my another class where I'm trying to get arrayList values**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalBloc _globalBloc = Provider.of<GlobalBloc>(context);

... 

 for (var medicine in _globalBloc.medicineList$.value) { //ERROR <--
        if (medicineName == medicine.medicineName) {
             return;
        }
 }
                     
}
```

**ERROR looks like this**

[image]

Comment: What is value intended to be here? Are you trying to access it as  a map?
If it's a list, your forLoop is good to go without using 'value'.

Comment: It's arrayList and for loop doesn't seems to work here as the list is wrapped into like `BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>>`

Comment: what do you get when you try to use `for (var medicine in _globalBloc.medicineList$)` ?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad - it gives, `The type 'BehaviorSubject<List<Medicine>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Now, You can try this, to get value from Bloc

```dart
List<Medicine> medList = [];
medList = await _globalBloc.medicineList$.first;
```

N.B: As of less reputation, unable to comment. That's why post as a answer.